# AppWarp in theoretic view

Tags: android, libgdx, appwarp

It is the first time, that I'm working on a multiplayer mode to my game, so maybe this is reason why I so many questions have.
So, I have read all the existing tutorials(also YouTube videos), but have some questions.(Because libgdx has already changed a lot since tutorials have published.)

1. How should a project folder structure look like? Which packages should I add to my android folder in `libGDX` project?
2. My existing single player game has 2 different roles. One for player and one for computer, with different motivations. It is a graph based game, they all playing by signing its vertices with two different colours.(The game has a mathematic base, a graph algorithm.) So, in this way all the two players codebase should be the same?
3. Maybe I need a screen with some listeners for the multiplayer game, and that is all? Can you please tell me some basics, about building this screen?

libGDX's changed project structure make it hard and complicated to interpret older `AppWarp` tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow our documentation for integration. I can suggest the steps that would help you in conversation of single to multiplayer Game.
Initialize AppWarp SDK at home screen.
Connect User when he open the application after the initialization
Once User will connected you can  create/Join Room API and enter in the Game Scene once join Room succeeded.

In Game scene whenever you play your turn you can send turn data with sendMove API.

Whenever game data is received you can check the nextTurn User and update the respective UI on your Game screen
So these are the steps you can use for single Player to multi Player conversion.

Let me know if you need more helps in game integration.